# Inserting text after a bookmark in openxml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, word-automation

I am looking for a way to insert some text after a bookmark in a word doc using openxml. So far, i have been able to locate the bookmark using the following:

```
var bookmarks = mainPart.Document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().ToList();
var bookMarkToWriteAfter = bookmarks.FirstOrDefault(bm => bm.Name == insertAfterBoomark.Name);
```

This bookmark in the word doc is a selection of two lines in the doc. I have to insert some text right after the two line selection. I have tried to insert text using the following:

```
var run = new Run();
run.Append(new Text("Hello World"));
bookMarkToWriteAfter .Parent.InsertAfterSelf(run);

mainPart.Document.Save();
```

This however does not produce the desired result. Does anyone know of the correct way to insert text right after a bookmark in a word doc using openxml?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using

```
bookMarkToWriteAfter.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(run);
```

you are trying to work with XML directly which is not always advisable with OpenXML.

Try This..

```
    Body body = mainPart.Document.GetFirstChild<Body>();
    var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

    //Iterate through the paragraphs to find the bookmarks inside
    foreach (var para in paras)
    {
        var bookMarkStarts = para.Elements<BookmarkStart>();
        var bookMarkEnds = para.Elements<BookmarkEnd>();


        foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in bookMarkStarts)
        {
            if (bookMarkStart.Name == bookmarkName)
            {
                //Get the id of the bookmark start to find the bookmark end
                var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
                var bookmarkEnd = bookMarkEnds.Where(i => i.Id.Value == id).First();

                var runElement = new Run(new Text("Hello World!!!"));

                para.InsertAfter(runElement, bookmarkEnd);

            }
        }
   }
   mainPart.Document.Save();
```

Comment: I have a requirement such that i need to find all the bookmarks in the entire document right off the bat. This is because something generic is being done to all of them at once before i do the text insertion. So is there a way to work with all bookmarks at once and not split up by paragraphs?

Comment: You may get a list of all bookmarks and work with them (depending on what you are trying to do with them), but for inserting texts, it is better to insert using paragraph elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assume that a bookmark starts and ends in one paragraph. Bookmarks can start and end in different elements and be children of:

bdo (§17.3.2.3); body (§17.2.2); comment (§17.13.4.2); customXml (§17.5.1.6); customXml (§17.5.1.4); customXml (§17.5.1.5); customXml (§17.5.1.3); deg (§22.1.2.26); del (§17.13.5.14); den (§22.1.2.28); dir (§17.3.2.8); docPartBody (§17.12.6); e (§22.1.2.32); endnote (§17.11.2); fldSimple (§17.16.19); fName (§22.1.2.37); footnote (§17.11.10); ftr (§17.10.3); hdr (§17.10.4); hyperlink (§17.16.22); ins (§17.13.5.18); lim (§22.1.2.52); moveFrom (§17.13.5.22); moveTo (§17.13.5.25); num (§22.1.2.75); oMath (§22.1.2.77); p (§17.3.1.22); rt (§17.3.3.24); rubyBase (§17.3.3.27); sdtContent (§17.5.2.34); sdtContent (§17.5.2.33); sdtContent (§17.5.2.35); sdtContent (§17.5.2.36); smartTag (§17.5.1.9); sub (§22.1.2.112); sup (§22.1.2.114); tbl (§17.4.38); tc (§17.4.66); tr (§17.4.79)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.bookmarkstart(v=office.15).aspx

This means you need to look at all the BookmarkEnd elements in the document when checking for the required BookmarkEnd element.

```
Body body = mainPart.Document.GetFirstChild<Body>();
var bookMarkStarts = body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();
var bookMarkEnds = body.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>();

foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in bookMarkStarts)
{
    if (bookMarkStart.Name == bookmarkName)
    {
        //Get the id of the bookmark start to find the bookmark end
        var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
        var bookmarkEnd = bookMarkEnds.Where(i => i.Id.Value == id).First();

        var runElement = new Run(new Text("Hello World!!!"));

        bookmarkEnd.Parent.InsertAfter(runElement, bookmarkEnd);
    }
}
mainPart.Document.Save();
```

You may want to check that a Run can be added to the parent and add to a different ancestor or create a new Paragraph.

(I would have liked to have added this as a comment to Flowerking's answer but I can't comment so I have modified their code in this answer.)