# Create doc file from template and adding data from database using open xml

Tags: entity-framework, templates, c#-4.0, openxml

I have a word template and I want to create doc file from that, also I want to replace add data in place of bookmarks present in the template.
I have been able to create a doc file, but I am not able to understand, how to add data in place of bookmarks?
My code till now:

```
private void CreateSampleWordDocument()
    {
        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "GeneralWelcomeLetter.dotx");
        string destinationFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Sample.docx");
        try
        {
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
            WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true);
            document.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

            DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingPart1 = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart;

            AttachedTemplate attachedTemplate1 = new AttachedTemplate() { Id = "relationId1" };

            documentSettingPart1.Settings.Append(attachedTemplate1);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Now to add data from database in place of bookmarks?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9774489/860243

Comment: Sure, let me check and I will get back to you regarding same.

Comment: That was a help, can you post this comment as an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: I tried to post the link as answer but as its short it's converted back to comment. I do not want to copy my own answer. Please consider making your own answer from your solution code. :)

Comment: Sure, can you answer my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351829/join-multiple-word-documents-into-one-open-xml