# Merge multiple word documents into one Open Xml

Tags: c#, merge, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I have around 10 word documents which I generate using open xml and other stuff.
Now I would like to create another word document and one by one I would like to join them into  this newly created document.
I wish to use open xml, any hint would be appreciable.
Below is my code:

```
 private void CreateSampleWordDocument()
    {
        //string sourceFile = Path.Combine("D:\\GeneralLetter.dot");
        //string destinationFile = Path.Combine("D:\\New.doc");
        string sourceFile = Path.Combine("D:\\GeneralWelcomeLetter.docx");
        string destinationFile = Path.Combine("D:\\New.docx");
        try
        {
            // Create a copy of the template file and open the copy
            //File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
            {
                // Change the document type to Document
                document.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                //Get the Main Part of the document
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

**Update( using AltChunks):**

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("D:\\Test.docx", true))
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 2) ;
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("D:\\Test1.docx", FileMode.Open))
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
            mainPart.Document
                .Body
                .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
```

Why this code overwrites the content of the last file when I use multiple files?
**Update 2:**

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("D:\\Test.docx", true))
        {

            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 3);
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("d:\\Test1.docx", FileMode.Open))
            {
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainPart.Document
                    .Body
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("d:\\Test2.docx", FileMode.Open))
            {
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainPart.Document
                    .Body
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            }
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("d:\\Test3.docx", FileMode.Open))
            {
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainPart.Document
                    .Body
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            } 
        }
```

This code is appending the Test2 data twice, in place of Test1 data as well.
Means I get:

```
Test
Test2
Test2
```

instead of :

```
Test
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: Like chirs pointed out, you are using same Id for all the AltChunk's. They must be unique.

Comment: Ok, its done now, Thank you for keeping up patience with me.

Comment: I am happy to see that you finally solved your issue :) Yep it was related to Altchunkid. I have edited my answer since it was maybe not very clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using openXML SDK only, you can use [`AltChunk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx) element to merge the multiple document into one.

This link [the-easy-way-to-assemble-multiple-word-documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/12/08/the-easy-way-to-assemble-multiple-word-documents.aspx) and this one [How to Use altChunk for Document Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx) provide some samples.

**EDIT 1**

Based on your code that uses `altchunk` in the updated question *(update#1)*, here is the VB.Net code I have tested and that works like a charm for me:

```
Using myDoc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open("D:\\Test.docx", True)
        Dim altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 2)
        Dim mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart
        Dim chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId)
        Using fileStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open("D:\\Test1.docx", IO.FileMode.Open)
            chunk.FeedData(fileStream)
        End Using
        Dim altChunk = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk()
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId
        mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph).Last())
        mainPart.Document.Save()
End Using
```

**EDIT 2**

The second issue *(update#2)*

> This code is appending the Test2 data twice, in place of Test1 data as
> well.

is related to `altchunkid`.

For each document you want to merge in the main document, you need to:

1. add an `AlternativeFormatImportPart` in the `mainDocumentPart` with an `Id` **which must be unique.** This element contains the inserted data
2. add in the body an `Altchunk` element in which you set the `id` to reference the previous `AlternativeFormatImportPart`.

In your code, you are using the same Id for all the `AltChunks`. It's why you see many time the same text.

I am not sure the altchunkid will be unique with your code: `string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 2);`

If you don't need to set a specific value, I recommend you to not set explicitly the `AltChunkId` when you add the `AlternativeFormatImportPart`. Instead, you get the one generated by the SDK like this:

VB.Net

```
Dim chunk As AlternativeFormatImportPart = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML)
Dim altchunkid As String = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chunk)
```

C#

```
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML);
string altchunkid = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chunk);
```

Comment: That is not performing what I want to do also there is no exception coming. I am posting my updated code with Altchunks.

Comment: Do I need to do something in the docx file as well, like adding bookmark type other action?

Comment: @ItiTyagi No, in my test, I have just created two files with a simple text (Text1 and Text2). And after running this code, the file Test.docx contains the two paragraphs when I open it.

Comment: You know what, I was having open office, so there it was not reflected, but when I opened the same in office, there it worked.

Comment: It is only overwriting the last one when I want to merge multiple

Comment: @ItiTyagi It shouldn't. Post your complete updated code with multiple files. Also see second edit concerning altchunkId.

Answer (score 15):

There is a nice wrapper API (Document Builder 2.2) around open xml specially designed to merge documents, with flexibility of choosing the paragraphs to merge etc. You can download it from [here](http://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771) (update: moved to [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools)).

The documentation and screen casts on how to use it are [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/documentbuilder.aspx).

**Update: Code Sample**

```
 var sources = new List<Source>();
 //Document Streams (File Streams) of the documents to be merged.
 foreach (var stream in documentstreams)
 {
        var tempms = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(tempms);
        sources.Add(new Source(new WmlDocument(stream.Length.ToString(), tempms), true));
 }

  var mergedDoc = DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources);
  mergedDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\TargetFilePath");
```

Types `Source` and `WmlDocument` are from Document Builder API.

You can even add the file paths directly if you choose to as:

```
sources.Add(new Source(new WmlDocument(@"C:\FileToBeMerged1.docx"));
sources.Add(new Source(new WmlDocument(@"C:\FileToBeMerged2.docx"));
```

Found this [Nice Comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/19/comparison-of-altchunk-to-the-documentbuilder-class.aspx) between `AltChunk` and `Document Builder` approaches to merge documents - helpful to choose based on ones requirements.

You can also use [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com) library to merge documents but I prefer Document Builder over this for merging documents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way in open xml through coding as this task is really eating me, and I can't use any other tool etc.

Comment: These libraries are opensource wrappers around OpenXml. Document Builder is using Open Xml sdk to do the merging and there are no hard dependencies. Merging documents is not a simple task, along with the content you have to migrate styles + other open xml parts without loosing the relationships! And this becomes a nightmare when you have pictures in the document. The source code of Document Builder Api will give you an idea of the same.

Comment: I just need to append content, as a page, so that I can print in one go.

Comment: The most simplest way to do it IMHO is to use Document Builder. I have added code snippet. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: The [Nice Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/comparison-of-altchunk-to-the-documentbuilder-class) between AltChunk and Document Builder has moved (thanks Eric!)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing missing in these answers is the `for` loop.

For those who just want to copy / paste it:

```
void MergeInNewFile(string resultFile, IList<string> filenames)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(resultFile, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
        mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());

        foreach (string filename in filenames)
        {
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML);
            string altChunkId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chunk);

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
            }

            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk { Id = altChunkId };
            mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(altChunk);
        }

        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

All credits go to Chris and yonexbat

Answer (score 1):

Easy to use in C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace WordMergeProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] word1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\word1.docx");
            byte[] word2 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\word2.docx");

            byte[] result = Merge(word1, word2);

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"..\..\word3.docx", result);
        }

        private static byte[] Merge(byte[] dest, byte[] src)
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

            var memoryStreamDest = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStreamDest.Write(dest, 0, dest.Length);
            memoryStreamDest.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var memoryStreamSrc = new MemoryStream(src);

            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStreamDest, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart altPart =
                    mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                altPart.FeedData(memoryStreamSrc);
                var altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                              OpenXmlElement lastElem = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<AltChunk>().LastOrDefault();
            if(lastElem == null)
            {
                lastElem = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last();
            }


            //Page Brake einfügen
            Paragraph pageBreakP = new Paragraph();
            Run pageBreakR = new Run();
            Break pageBreakBr = new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page };

            pageBreakP.Append(pageBreakR);
            pageBreakR.Append(pageBreakBr);                

            return memoryStreamDest.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something missing from the code in this answer.

Comment: What are you doing with lastElem? It seems to be set but then not used.

Comment: This method doesn't work.  Only the first doc is added to the output.

Comment: This code is incomplete for required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestFusionWord
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void MergeDocx(List<string> ListPathFilesToMerge, string DestinationPathFile, bool OverWriteDestination, bool WithBreakPage)
        {
            #region Control arguments

            List<string> ListError = new List<string>();
            if (ListPathFilesToMerge == null || ListPathFilesToMerge.Count == 0)
            {
                ListError.Add("Il n'y a aucun fichier à fusionner dans la liste passée en paramètre ListPathFilesToMerge");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in ListPathFilesToMerge.Where(x => Path.GetExtension(x.ToLower()) != ".docx"))
                {
                    ListError.Add(string.Format("Le fichier '{0}' indiqué dans la liste passée en paramètre ListPathFilesToMerge n'a pas l'extension .docx", item));
                }

                foreach (var item in ListPathFilesToMerge.Where(x => !File.Exists(x)))
                {
                    ListError.Add(string.Format("Le fichier '{0}' indiqué dans la liste passée en paramètre ListPathFilesToMerge n'existe pas", item));
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DestinationPathFile))
            {
                ListError.Add("Le fichier destination FinalPathFile passé en paramètre ne peut être vide");
            }
            else
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(DestinationPathFile.ToLower()) != ".docx")
                {
                    ListError.Add(string.Format("Le fichier destination '{0}' indiqué dans le paramètre DestinationPathFile n'a pas l'extension .docx", DestinationPathFile));
                }

                if (File.Exists(DestinationPathFile) && !OverWriteDestination)
                {
                    ListError.Add(string.Format("Le fichier destination '{0}' existe déjà. Utilisez l'argument OverWriteDestination si vous souhaitez l'écraser", DestinationPathFile));
                }
            }

            if (ListError.Any())
            {
                string MessageError = "Des erreurs ont été rencontrés, détail : " + Environment.NewLine + ListError.Select(x => "- " + x).Aggregate((x, y) => x + Environment.NewLine + y);
                throw new ArgumentException(MessageError);
            }

            #endregion Control arguments

            #region Merge Files

            //Suppression du fichier destination (aucune erreur déclenchée si le fichier n'existe pas)
            File.Delete(DestinationPathFile);

            //Création du fichier destination à vide
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(DestinationPathFile, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
                mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
                document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }

            //Fusion des documents
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DestinationPathFile, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

                for (int i = 0; i < ListPathFilesToMerge.Count; i++)
                {
                    string currentpathfile = ListPathFilesToMerge[i];
                    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML);
                    string altchunkid = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chunk);

                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(currentpathfile, FileMode.Open))
                        chunk.FeedData(fileStream);

                    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                    altChunk.Id = altchunkid;

                    OpenXmlElement last = body.Elements().LastOrDefault(e => e is AltChunk || e is Paragraph);
                    body.InsertAfter(altChunk, last);

                    if (WithBreakPage && i < ListPathFilesToMerge.Count - 1) // If its not the last file, add breakpage
                    {
                        last = body.Elements().LastOrDefault(e => e is AltChunk || e is Paragraph);
                        last.InsertAfterSelf(new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
                    }
                }

                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }

            #endregion Merge Files
        }

        private static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string DestinationPathFile = @"C:\temp\testfusion\docfinal.docx";

                List<string> ListPathFilesToMerge = new List<string>()
                                    {
                                        @"C:\temp\testfusion\fichier1.docx",
                                        @"C:\temp\testfusion\fichier2.docx",
                                        @"C:\temp\testfusion\fichier3.docx"
                                    };

                ListPathFilesToMerge.Sort(); //Sort for always have the same file

                MergeDocx(ListPathFilesToMerge, DestinationPathFile, true, true);

#if DEBUG
                Process.Start(DestinationPathFile); //open file
#endif
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
                //Log exception here
                return -1;
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```